# Generate all possible ordered subset from a set

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm aware how to generate all possible subsets from a set incorporating bit twiddling. For instance,

```
//Get if nth position's bit is set
bool IsBitSet(int num, int bit)
{
    return 1 == ((num >> bit) & 1);
}

int subsetMaxIterCount = pow(2, someList.size());
for (int i = 0; i < subsetMaxIterCount; i++) {
    vector<A> subset;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < jobList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (IsBitSet(jobSubsetIdx, i)) {
                //Add to subset here
            }
        }

        //Here we have a subset for some i
    }
```

However, this doesn't take into account of ordering.

For instance, if I had a set of {1, 2, 3}, the above algorithm generates subsets of:

{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1,2,3}

What I need in reality is this

{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1,2,3}, {2, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}

Not sure if the above list is exhaustive. What's an effective algorithm in generating something like this? (Is this all possible subsets with permutation by the way?)

Comment: Yes. Generate the the subsets, then for each subset generate the permutations.

Comment: std::next_permutation and std::prev_permutation

Comment: voted to close as lacking reproducible example

Comment: I have an answer to your joystick direction question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way we generate the subsets using bit twiddling, every subset is sorted within it `e.g. {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}`. You can generate permutation for each subset using `next_permutation`

```
vector<vector<int>> mySubsetGenerator(vector<vector<int>>& subsets) {
    vector<vector<int>> extendedSubset;
    for(int i = 0; i < subsets.size(); ++i) {
         do {
             extendedSubset.push_back(subsets[i]);
         } while(next_permutation(subsets[i].begin(), subsets[i].end()));
    }
    return extendedSubset;
}
```

Moreover, you can use only backtracking to generate all possible permutations by taking one or more elements of array.